# mysql_connect в php7

Tags: mysql, битрикс, php7

Имеем:
1) Сервер c php7 где есть mysqli, pdo , но отсутствует mysql_connect
2) Сайт с древней версией CMS, где все на mysql. Переписывать все на mysqli не вариант.
Как совместить первое со вторым?

Comment: Даунгрейд PHP до версии, оборудованной библиотекой со старой технологией доступа.

Comment: Так как старые функции не существуют, то можно их написать, что бы они в свою очередь вызывали mysqli. Ведь в основном используются штук 10. Попробуйте.

Comment: Как вариант - установить более старую версию на сервер рядом с семеркой и настроить сервер. О настройке можно почитать здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/245549/

Comment: Битрикс с 15й версии уже mysqli поддерживает, это ж насколько он у Вас древний?